# go / geany : configure build command

Tags: linux, build, go, geany

With an old version of go I could configure the build command in geany as

```
go install "%d"
```

But it seems that in Go1 you cannot provide to `go install` the absolute path.

So I'd like to have a command enabling me in geany to run

```
go install mypackagename
```

when my edited file is

```
/some/path/to/my/project/go/src/mypackagename/editedfile.go
```

What can I put in the settings to obtain that ?

Please consider that I'm a linux noob and that there may exist a trivial solution using a combination of standard shell commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like

```
cd "%d" && go install
```

It changes the current working directory to the directory supplied by geany and
runs `go install` if the directory change was successful.

This only works if geany is executing the build commands in a shell. Without that,
there's no `cd` (the shell provides it as an inbuilt command) and this solution won't work.

Your only hope then is, to configure the current working dir for the build process in geany.

Comment: I build another answer from this, trying to provide a reference for command configuration for Go in Geany.

Answer (score 1):

Using nemo's good answer, here's a reference on how Geany can be configured for golang.

**Compile (F8) :**

```
go build "%f"
```

**Install (F9) :**

```
cd "%d" && go install
```

**Test :**

```
cd "%d" && go test
```

**Run (F5) :**

```
go run "%f"
```

Note that basic Go support in Geany (including colorization) [is described here](http://go-lang.cat-v.org/text-editors/geany/).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a one-line multi-command thing.  As in:
cd /path/to/root/code/dir; go install mypackagename

Answer (score -2):

```
go install import-path
```

installs $GOPATH/src/import-path. Last element of import-path must correspond to the package name in source(s) in that directory.

Comment: The question is how do you configure geany so that the build command produces this command.

Comment: The answer is to configure geany to follow the discussed rules,  eg. as "GOPATH=... go build foo/bar". Also the answer is that absolute paths are not suported  by the go tool.

Comment: You're just repeating the premises of the question. What I want to know is HOW to configure geany to do this.